# Could not locate the assembly "Windows" on GitHub actions

Tags: c#, winforms, github-actions

I'm trying to build a Windows Forms application on GitHub Actions using windows-latest platform.

I can successfully setup MSBuild and Nuget, I have also run nuget restore successfully but when I try to run `msbuild .\MyProject.csproj` I get the following error:

```
ResolveAssemblyReferences:
  Primary reference "Windows".
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2202,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Windows". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
```

Comment: What framework are you targeting, and which runtimes/SDKs are installed on the computer doing the compiling?

Comment: I'm targeting .NET Framework 4.5.2 and from https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md it seems Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.2.TargetingPack is installed.